# Just some of the file thumbnails are being shown

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

I am importing some files to a folder using  everything is ok and all the files get inserted normally, but the problem begins when I try to show thumbnails of these files on my browser. In this case just some of the files can be shown perfectly and others are shown az empty rectangular! While all the files are located in the same folder!
I investigated more and realized that the images that their original source(on computer) was close to the folder path are being shown perfectly and others not.

For instance my folder locates in: c://xampp/htdocs/test/folder
I have put all the picturs in folder, but just the images that originally where available at c://xampp/htdocs/test are being shown and not others.

Please help me

the code:

```
    $images=array();  
    $dir_handler = opendir('test/folder') or die("Unable to open $path");  
    $i=0;    
    while($file = readdir($dir_handler))
    {            
    if(is_dir($file)) 
    continue;        
    else if($file != '.' && $file != '..' && $file != 'index.php')
    {                    
    $images[$i]=$file;
    $i++;     
    }       
    }      
    sort($images);

    for($i=0; $i<sizeof($images); $i++) 
    {              

    echo "<a href=".chr(34).$path.$images[$i].chr(34)."><img style='border:1px solid #666666; width:100px;height:100px; margin: 10px;' src='".$images[$i]."'/></a>";

    }        closedir($dir);
```

Comment: You could just have `href=\""..."\"...` instead of those chr(34)'s. or better yet, use a [HEREDOC](http://php.net/heredoc). You're also missing `$path` on your img tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be more helpful to use SPL's Directory iterator in this case.

In this code example, I'm assuming your path was to 'test/folder' - which contained images and an index.php file.

```
$path = 'test/folder';
foreach (new DirectoryIterator($path) as $fileInfo) {
    if ($fileInfo->isFile() && $fileInfo->getFilename() != 'index.php') {
        $image = "{$path}/{$fileInfo->getFilename()}";
        echo "<a href='{$image}'><img src='{$image}'></a>"; // style as appropriate
    }
}
```

This creates a new DirectoryIterator on your path.  Then, if the result is indeed a file, and not named index.php, the variable $image is populated with the path and the filename.  The echo statement has a shorter version of your example code to output the a/img tag combination.

Comment: thanks alot, it works but it does not show the thumbnails of folders. I have created some folders inside the main folder but their thumbnails are not being shown!

Comment: No problem - check out [SPL RecursiveDirectoryIterator](http://php.net/recursivedirectoryiterator) and modify the code accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I think your images src path should be `src='folder/".$images[$i]."'`

Comment: oh thank U very much, It really solved half of the problem. Some other images are also being shown now. But I wonder why some others can not be shown yet!!

Comment: You should use `print_r($images)` to see if that array contains all the images you need, and which are their file name.. I think there are some unrecognized charachters. You may try to rename all files without having spaces and other charachters than `[a-z][0-9]` and `-`. You should verify if your php script file is UTF-8 encoded..